# PySpark: Empty RDD on reading gzipped BSON files

Tags: mongodb, pyspark, bson

I have a script to analyse BSON dumps, however it works only with uncompressed files. I get an empty RDD while reading gz bson files.

```
pyspark_location = 'lib/pymongo_spark.py'
HDFS_HOME = 'hdfs://1.1.1.1/'
INPUT_FILE = 'big_bson.gz'


class BsonEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, ObjectId):
            return str(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, datetime):
            return obj.isoformat()
        return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)


def setup_spark_with_pymongo(app_name='App'):
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName(app_name)
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    sc.addPyFile(pyspark_location)
    return sc


def main():
    spark_context = setup_spark_with_pymongo('PysparkApp')
    filename = HDFS_HOME + INPUT_FILE
    import pymongo_spark
    pymongo_spark.activate()
    rdd = spark_context.BSONFileRDD(filename)
    print(rdd.first())  #Raises ValueError("RDD is empty")
```

I am using mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar, mongo-hadoop-spark-1.5.2.jar, pymongo-3.2.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64 and pymongo_spark in along with spark-submit.
The version of Spark deployed is 1.6.1 along with Hadoop 2.6.4.

I am aware that the library does not support splitting compressed BSON files, however it should with a single split. 
I have got hundreds of compressed BSON files to analyse and deflating each of them doesn't seem to be a viable option.

Any idea how should I proceed further?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested in the environment: `mongo-hadoop-spark-1.5.2.jar`, spark version 1.6.1 for Hadoop 2.6.4, Pymongo 3.2.2. The source file is an output from [mongodump compressed](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#compress-the-output), and a small size file for a single split (uncompressed collection size of 105MB). Running through PySpark:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
import pymongo_spark
pymongo_spark.activate()
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("pyspark-bson")
file_path = "/file/example_bson.gz"
rdd = sc.BSONFileRDD(file_path)
rdd.first()
```

It is able to read the compressed BSON file, and listed the first document. Please make sure you can reach the input file, and the file is in the correct BSON format.